# How to wait between functions in Selenium-Webdriver NodeJS test?

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am trying to run a test to submit a form. I use selenium grid (with LambdaTest Tool) and NodeJS. I want to test if it is possible to submit the form on Safari browser.When I look at the screen video on Lambdatest I see that everything happens extreme fast.I want to wait first 10 seconds until page fully loads and fill half of fields wait a bit then the other half, scroll up and down to see all the forms before submit and at the end click on submit button.I tried to do it with setTimeout method but before the page load function check_pages runs and I keep gettin Failed on console.

```
    /*
        LambdaTest selenium automation sample example
        Configuration
        ----------
        username: Username can be found at automation dashboard
        accessKey:  AccessKey can be generated from automation dashboard or profile section

        Result
        -------
        Execute NodeJS Automation Tests on LambdaTest Distributed Selenium Grid
    */
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

    /*
        Setup remote driver
        Params
        ----------
        platform : Supported platform - (Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7,  macOS High Sierra, macOS Sierra, OS X El Capitan, OS X Yosemite, OS X Mavericks)
        browserName : Supported platform - (chrome, firefox, Internet Explorer, MicrosoftEdge, Safari)
        version :  Supported list of version can be found at https://www.lambdatest.com/capabilities-generator/
    */

    // username: Username can be found at automation dashboard
    const USERNAME = '.......';

    // AccessKey:  AccessKey can be generated from automation dashboard or profile section
    const KEY = '....';

    // gridUrl: gridUrl can be found at automation dashboard
    const GRID_HOST = 'hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub';

    function fillandsubmitform() {
        // Setup Input capabilities
        const capabilities = {
            platform: 'macOS Mojave',
            browserName : "Safari",
            version: '12.0',
            resolution: '1280x960',
            network: true,
            visual: true,
            console: true,
            video: true,
            name: 'Test 22', // name of the test
            build: 'NodeJS build' // name of the build
        }

        // URL: https://{username}:{accessKey}@hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub
        const gridUrl = 'https://' + USERNAME + ':' + KEY + '@' + GRID_HOST;

        // setup and build selenium driver object
        const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .usingServer(gridUrl)
            .withCapabilities(capabilities)
            .build();



        // navigate to a url, search for a text and get title of page
        driver.get('https://www....').then(function() {   

                setTimeout(function () {  

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_genderId_1')).click();
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_firstName')).sendKeys('NodeJS');       
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_lastname')).sendKeys('Test');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_streetAndNumber')).sendKeys('on Lambda Selenium Grid');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_zip')).sendKeys('69115');
            },7000);
            setTimeout(function () {  

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_city')).sendKeys('Berlin');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_selectedLanguage')).sendKeys('Deutschland');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_email')).sendKeys('test@gmael.com');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_phone')).sendKeys('017625856884');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_birthDate')).sendKeys('07.07.2019');
            driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight/2,0);');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('chk_accept')).click();
            },10000);
            scrollUpDown();
            setTimeout(function () { 
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('submitFormButton')).click(); 
            }, 15000);

            driver.wait(check_page, 20000);   


            function scrollUpDown(){
                setTimeout(function () {
                    driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 2);');
                   },2000);
                   setTimeout(function () {
                      driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 2);');
                     },2000);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                      driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 2);');
                     },2000);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                      driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 3);');
                     },2000);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, -window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                      driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                     },2000);
                     setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                        driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 3);');
                       },2000);
            }
            function check_page(){
                var promise = driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
                    if(title==='Thank you for subbmission'){
                        console.log('Success');
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Failed --' + title);
                    }
                });
                return promise;
            }


        });
    }

fillandsubmitform();
```

Console error

c:\Users...\newTest>node index.js
Failed 
Failed 
Failed 
Failed

(node:3524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 20222ms
    at c:\Users....-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:841:17
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3524) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: did you try with  driver.wait method ? Also as per there docs  driver.findElement  is promise so you can use await or then

Comment: Also add console error you are getting

Comment: I have added now console i guess check title function runs before the form is sent.How can I use driver wait?

Comment: The error suggests that  you didnt handle promise for this to run do this setTimeout(asyn function () {  

           await  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_genderId_1')).click();
           await  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('_field_firstName')).sendKeys('NodeJS');       
            },7000); for all findElements method